# How to install PostGIS for Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, postgis

So I'm following the DOCS and just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/

Do I just create a file called migrations.py with:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CreateExtension
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        CreateExtension('postgis'),
        ...
    ]
```

and drop it in my project directory?  And then run python manage.py makemigrations ?

Comment: `python manage.py migrate` not `makemigrations`

Comment: Where in my project directory?  Just the root?

Answer (score 4):

Still the better way ist to create extension directly by making a sql query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

After that you just have to navigate to your project-root (there is a manage.py file inside) and run `python manage.py migrate` (since django 1.9 - before v.1.9 first run `python manage.py makemigrations` and after that `python manage.py migrate`)

But if you want to use your code, you have to add it to "models.py".
This is the file called by `"python manage.py migrate"`

So your models.py looks like:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CreateExtension
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        CreateExtension('postgis'),
    ]


class model1(models.Model):
     geom = models.GeometryField(srid=4326,blank=True,null=True)
     name = models.TextField(null=True)
```